# Scala : How to use Global Config case class across application

Tags: scala, case-class

I am new to scala, just started with my scala first application.

I have defined my config file under the resources folder, application.conf

```
  projectname{
     "application" {
     "host":127.0.0.1
     "port":8080
    }
 }
```

I have wrote one config parser file to parse from config file to case class

```
    case class AppConfig (config: Config) {
      val host = config.getString("projectname.application.host")
      val port = config.getInt("projectname.application.port")
    }
```

In my grpc server file, i have declared config as

```
    val config = AppConfig(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"))
```

I want to use this config variable across application, rather than loading application.conf file everytime.

I want to have one bootstrap function which will parse this config one time, making it available across application

Comment: What type of application do you have? Is it a standalone one? Is it using any framework? The entrypoint of the application (which depends on its type) would be a good place to load the config...

Comment: Its akka-grpc based application. Yes, even I want to load config at entry point only, inside my run function. The only issue facing is to have that config variable accessible across my application, inside helpers files to fetch data from any database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this automatically with [PureConfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig).

Add Pure Config to you `build.sbt` with:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.github.pureconfig" %% "pureconfig" % "0.11.0"
```

and reload the sbt shell and update your dependencies.

Now, let's say you have the following `resource.conf` file:

```
host: example.com
port: 80
user: admin
password: admin_password
```

You can define a case class called `AppConfig`:

```scala
case class AppConfig(
    host: String,
    port: Int,
    user: String,
    password: String
)
```

And create an instance of it, populated with the application config, using the `loadConfig` method:

```scala
import pureconfig.generic.auto._

val errorsOrConfig: Either[ConfigReaderFailures, AppConfig] = pureconfig.loadConfig[AppConfig]
```

This returns Either an error or your AppConfig, depending on the values in the config itself.
For example, if the value of `port` above will be `eighty`, instead of 80, you will get a detailed error, saying that the second config line (with the `port: eighty`) contained a string, but the only valid expected type is a number:

```
ConfigReaderFailures(
    ConvertFailure(
        reason = WrongType(
        foundType = STRING,
        expectedTypes = Set(NUMBER)
    ),
    location = Some(
        ConfigValueLocation(
           new URL("file:~/repos/example-project/target/scala-2.12/classes/application.conf"),
           lineNumber = 2
        )
    ),
    path = "port"
    )
)
```

You can use `loadConfigOrThrow` if you want to get `AppConfig` instead of an Either.

After you load this config once at the start of your application (as close as possible to your main function), you can use dependency injection to pass it along to all the other classes, simply by passing the AppConfig in the constructor.

If you would like to wire up your Logic class (and other services) with the config case class using [MacWire](https://github.com/adamw/macwire), as Krzysztof suggested in one of his options, you can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542854/1077641).

The plain example (without *MacWire*), looks like this:

```scala
package com.example

import com.example.config.AppConfig

object HelloWorld extends App {
 val config: AppConfig = pureconfig.loadConfigOrThrow[AppConfig]
 val logic = new Logic(config)
}

class Logic(config: AppConfig) {
   // do something with config
}
```

Where the AppConfig is defined in `AppConfig.scala`

```scala
package com.example.config

case class AppConfig(
    host: String,
    port: Int,
    user: String,
    password: String
)
```

As a bonus, when you use this config variable in your IDE, you will get code completion.

Moreover, your config may be built from the [supported types](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/built-in-supported-types.html), such as String, Boolean, Int, etc, but also from other case classes that are build from the supported types (this is since a case class represents a value object, that contains data), as well as lists and options of supported types.
This allows you to "class up" a complicated config file and get code completion. For instance, in `application.conf`:

```
name: hotels_best_dishes
host: "https://example.com"
port: 80
hotels: [
  "Club Hotel Lutraky Greece",
  "Four Seasons",
  "Ritz",
  "Waldorf Astoria"
]
min-duration: 2 days
currency-by-location {
  us = usd
  england = gbp
  il = nis
}
accepted-currency: [usd, gbp, nis]
application-id: 00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff
ssh-directory: /home/whoever/.ssh
developer: {
  name: alice,
  age: 20
}
```

Then define a config case class in your code:

```scala
import java.net.URL
import java.util.UUID
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration
import pureconfig.generic.EnumCoproductHint
import pureconfig.generic.auto._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

sealed trait Currency
case object Usd extends Currency
case object Gbp extends Currency
case object Nis extends Currency

object Currency {
  implicit val currencyHint: EnumCoproductHint[Currency] = new EnumCoproductHint[Currency]
}

case class Config(
  name: String,
  host: URL,
  port: Int,
  hotels: List[String],
  minDuration: FiniteDuration,
  currencyByLocation: Map[String, Currency],
  acceptedCurrency: List[Currency],
  applicationId: UUID,
  sshDirectory: java.nio.file.Path,
  developer: Person
)
```

And load it with:

```scala
val config: Config = pureconfig.loadConfigOrThrow[Config]
```

Comment: Just a small doubt, this AppConfig will be accessible in another file as well or  I have to again use  - AppConfig = pureconfig.loadConfigOrThrow[AppConfig]. Can you please help with this. I am struggling to access in another file

Comment: Hi Rakesh, it will be accessible in another file.
If you defined your `AppConfig` class in a package called `com.rakesh`, you need to import it on the other file `Logic.scala` with `import com.rakesh.AppConfig` and define `AppConfig` as a constructor argument for the `Logic` class

Comment: I edited my answer to provide you an example. Let me know if this is clear or not. good luck!

Answer (score 4):

There are some possibilities to handle your problem:

1. Use runtime dependency injection framework like **guice**. You can use [extension for scala](https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice).
2. Use implicits to handle it. You just need to create an object, which will hold your implicit config:

   ```
   object Implicits {
      implicit val config = AppConfig(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"))
   }
   ```

   And then you can just add `implicit config: Config` to your arguments list when you need it:

   ```
   def process(n: Int)(implicit val config: Config) = ??? //as method parameter

   case class Processor(n: Int)(implicit val config: AppConfig) //or as class field
   ```

   And use it like:

   ```
   import Implicits._

   process(5) //config passed implicitly here

   Processor(10) //and here
   ```

   A great advantage of it is you can pass `config` manually for tests:

   ```
   process(5)(config)
   ```

   The downside of this approach is, that having a lot of implicit resolution in your app, will make compilation slow, but it shouldn't be a problem if your app is not humongous.
3. Make config a field of your classes (it is called constructor injection).

   ```
   class Foo(config: Config).
   ```

   Then you can wire-up your dependencies manually, like:

   ```
   val config: AppConfig = AppConfig()

   val foo = Foo(config) //you need to pass config manually to constructors in your object graph
   ```

   or you can use a framework which can automate it for you, like [macwire](https://github.com/adamw/macwire):

   ```
   val config = wire[AppConfig]
   val foo = wire[Foo]
   ```
4. You can use a pattern called [cake-pattern](https://coderwall.com/p/t_rapw/cake-pattern-in-scala-self-type-annotations-explicitly-typed-self-references-explained). It works fine for small-sized applications, but the bigger your app is, the clunkier this approach gets.

What is **NOT** a good approach is using global singleton like this:

```
object ConfigHolder {
    val Config: AppConfig = ???
}
```

And then use it like:

```
def process(n: Int) = {
    val host = ConfigHolder.Config.host // anti-pattern
}
```

It is bad because it makes mocking your config for tests very difficult and the whole testing process becomes clunky.

In my opinion, if your app is not very big, you should use implicits.

If you want to learn more on this topic, check [this great guide](http://di-in-scala.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

You should define the fields as parameters of you case class.

```
final case class AppConfig(host: String, port: Int)
```

Then you overload the apply method of your companion object

```
object AppConfig {
  def apply(config: Config): AppConfig = {
    val host = config.getString("projectname.application.host")
    val port = config.getInt("projectname.application.port")
    AppConfig(host, port)
  } 
}
```

However the simplest way to process configuration with case classes is to use [pureconfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use this config variable across application, rather than loading application.conf file everytime.

Just put it in an `object`, like

```
object MyConfig {
  lazy val config = AppConfig(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"))
}
```

> I want to have one bootstrap function which will parse this config one time, making it available across application

As soon as you call `MyConfig.config` it is loaded just once - as `object` is a *Singleton*. So no special bootstrap is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're trying to achieve is called Dependency Injection. From Martin Fowler's [post](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection) on this topic

> The basic idea of the Dependency Injection is to have a separate object, an assembler, that populates a field in the lister class with an appropriate implementation for the finder interface.

Register this configuration instance in a Dependency Injection tool like [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice).

```
class AppModule(conf: AppConfiguration) extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[AppConfiguration]).toInstance(conf)
  }
}

....

// somewhere in the code
import com.google.inject.Inject

class FooClass @Inject() (config: AppConfiguration)
```

Comment: A little bit info on the downvote would be nice. The questioner has clearly asked for "I want to use this config variable across application, rather than loading application.conf file everytime." How is this answer not relevant to the question?

Comment: OP definitely asks about DI for config, so your answer is definitely relevant. +1 from me :)

Comment: It was a downwote from me. I was disagreeing with advertising non-idiomatic reflection-based frameworks to a newcomer. For such small problems there are usually dozens way to solve it. And downwoting in my opinion is a right tool to distract people from approaches that one considers harmful.

Comment: I don't think guice is not-idiomatic in Scala. It is the default DI framework used by Play. I, of course, agree with the opinion, that reflection-based frameworks have serious flaws, but it's not like runtime DI is never used in Scala world.

Comment: I'd say that Play is not idiomatic itself but it's off-topic.